# Jenkins Windows slave fails to connect to Linux master through JNLP (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect)

Tags: jenkins

I have some issues connecting Windows Jenkins slaves to a Linux Jenkins master through JNLP.

- Linux Master: Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits) / Jenkins 1.514. Jenkins access security set to "Everybody has access to all functionnalities" (sorry for possible inaccurate translation)
- Windows Slave : Windows 7 (32 bits), on a domain. Firewall and anti-virus are disabled. Same issue with an WinXP cmputer.

When I start the Jenkins slave on the Windows machine by a command like:

```
javaws.exe http://MYSERVER:8080/computer/MYSLAVE/slave-agent.jnlp
```

or a command like:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://MYSERVER:8080/computer/MYSLAVE/slave-agent.jnlp
```

... I get:

```
[... several retries before...]
mai 14, 2013 11:21:26 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Failed to connect to MYSERVER:51130
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to MYSERVER:51130
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:316)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:194)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:305)
        ... 1 more
```

If I run `tcpdump` on the Linux computer, I see communication between the slave and the master, port 51130...

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, did you manage to fix this somehow?

Comment: Does the Linux system have a firewall that is blocking the port?

Comment: Having identical issue.  Got both firewalls turned off, not getting any data from tcpdump.